# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastChild' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Face Matching Game</title>
 <h2>Matching Game</h2>
 <p>Click on the EXTRA face on the left side</p>
 <style type="text/css">
  div { position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 550px; background-color: maroon }
  img { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px}
  #rightSide { left: 650px; border-left: 2px solid black; }
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var NUM_OF_FACES = 0;
  var THE_LEFT_SIDE, THE_RIGHT_SIDE;
  //Function to generate faces
  function generateFaces() {
   THE_LEFT_SIDE = document.getElementById("leftSide");
   THE_RIGHT_SIDE = document.getElementById("rightSide");
   NUM_OF_FACES += 5;
   var image;
   while(NUM_OF_FACES>0){
    image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "smile.png";
    image.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()* (THE_LEFT_SIDE.offsetHeight - 100)) + "px";
    image.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()* (THE_LEFT_SIDE.offsetWidth - 100)) + "px";
    THE_LEFT_SIDE.appendChild(image);
    NUM_OF_FACES -= 1;
    //console.log(image.style.top, image.style.left )
   }
   var leftSideImages = THE_LEFT_SIDE.cloneNode(true);
   leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
   THE_RIGHT_SIDE.appendChild(leftSideImages);
  }//end generatefaces()

  function deleteFaces(argument) {
   while(THE_LEFT_SIDE.firstChild){
    THE_LEFT_SIDE.removeChild(THE_LEFT_SIDE.firstChild);
   }
   while(THE_RIGHT_SIDE.firstChild){
    THE_RIGHT_SIDE.removeChild(THE_RIGHT_SIDE.firstChild);
   }
  }//end deleteFaces()

  var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  THE_LEFT_SIDE = document.getElementById("leftSide");
  THE_RIGHT_SIDE = document.getElementById("rightSide");
  //Event handling
  THE_LEFT_SIDE.lastChild.onclick = function goToNextLevel() {
   alert("You clicked on correct face.");
   deleteFaces();
   generatefaces();
  };
  theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
   alert("Game Over!!");
   theBody.onclick = null;
   THE_LEFT_SIDE.lastChild.onclick = null;
  };
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
 <div id="leftSide"></div>
 <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am beginner in Javascript and ran into a problem while doing an assignment.
It is Fact Matching game and you have to click the extra face on the left side and game continues until you click somewhere else than extra face on left.
Above is the HTML file and JS code is embedded in it.

I am getting an error as: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastChild' of null` at line number 48, which is `onclick` event handler function on `lastChild` of `THE_LEFT_SIDE` div. I don't know how it is coming and what is the problem with my code?
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like `THE_LEFT_SIDE` is null at the time you are attempting to add a listener. Try putting the listener additions into a function that is executed after `generateFaces()`

Comment: The `THE_LEFT_SIDE` is empty until the `generateFaces` function is called on `onload` of `body`. Put `event handlers` code inside `<body>` in the last or inside `generateFaces` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are trying to access the element with id `leftSide` before it has been added to the DOM.**

If you move your script to the end of the page body, you will no longer see this error, but a different, unrelated one instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Face Matching Game</title>
 <h2>Matching Game</h2>
 <p>Click on the EXTRA face on the left side</p>
 <style type="text/css">
  div { position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 550px; background-color: maroon }
  img { position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px}
  #rightSide { left: 650px; border-left: 2px solid black; }
 </style>
 
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
 <div id="leftSide"></div>
 <div id="rightSide"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  var NUM_OF_FACES = 0;
  var THE_LEFT_SIDE, THE_RIGHT_SIDE;
  //Function to generate faces
  function generateFaces() {
   THE_LEFT_SIDE = document.getElementById("leftSide");
   THE_RIGHT_SIDE = document.getElementById("rightSide");
   NUM_OF_FACES += 5;
   var image;
   while(NUM_OF_FACES>0){
    image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "smile.png";
    image.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()* (THE_LEFT_SIDE.offsetHeight - 100)) + "px";
    image.style.left = Math.floor(Math.random()* (THE_LEFT_SIDE.offsetWidth - 100)) + "px";
    THE_LEFT_SIDE.appendChild(image);
    NUM_OF_FACES -= 1;
    //console.log(image.style.top, image.style.left )
   }
   var leftSideImages = THE_LEFT_SIDE.cloneNode(true);
   leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
   THE_RIGHT_SIDE.appendChild(leftSideImages);
  }//end generatefaces()

  function deleteFaces(argument) {
   while(THE_LEFT_SIDE.firstChild){
    THE_LEFT_SIDE.removeChild(THE_LEFT_SIDE.firstChild);
   }
   while(THE_RIGHT_SIDE.firstChild){
    THE_RIGHT_SIDE.removeChild(THE_RIGHT_SIDE.firstChild);
   }
  }//end deleteFaces()

  var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  THE_LEFT_SIDE = document.getElementById("leftSide");
  THE_RIGHT_SIDE = document.getElementById("rightSide");
  //Event handling
  THE_LEFT_SIDE.lastChild.onclick = function goToNextLevel() {
   alert("You clicked on correct face.");
   deleteFaces();
   generatefaces();
  };
  theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
   alert("Game Over!!");
   theBody.onclick = null;
   THE_LEFT_SIDE.lastChild.onclick = null;
  };
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah. Why is that?

Comment: Your code is executed sequentially. If the browser encounters the JavaScript before the HTML elements, the JavaScript is executed before the HTML elements are rendered. Move your code into the body's `onload` event handler to avoid that -- this will be executed after the whole body is rendered.

Comment: I have put that event handler THE_LEFT_SIDE.lastChild.onclick  into inside generateFaces() and it is working fine. What difference did it make and how it is different than previous one?

Comment: As I said, one is executed before the complete DOM tree was created, the other one after. If the element you are trying to operate on does not exist yet, you cannot add event handlers to it.

Comment: Is it because this `onclick` event handler can be invoked even if full page is loaded? Any there any standards to how to write event handlers better and where to write them?